# How to monitor my iPhone URLs access?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

If I want to write an iPhone app to monitor both my Browser and my other apps' URL logs, is that doable?

Moreover, can I define a list of URLs that I prohibit other apps and browser to access? (Something like parental control, but through an installed app)

Answer (score 0):

You should use a configuration profile to configure restrictions. To monitor the browser activity one would need a jailbroken device to e.g. read the history located in /var/mobile/Media/Safari/.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneConfigurationProfileRef/Introduction/Introduction.html